# Application title doesn't show in windows taskbar

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'm trying to figure out why every Winforms program I compile outside of Visual Studio doesn't show the title next to the little icon when right-clicking on the application icon located on the Windows Taskbar at the bottom of the desktop.

I have included:

```
Me.Text = "Title"
Me.Name = "Title"
```

What am I missing,can anyone help me?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

When compiling using a hand-coded .vb file with vbc.exe from the command prompt the program doesn't display the title in the Windows Taskbar. However, when compiled using Visual Studio it displays the title next to the small icon.

Comment: add some more details

Comment: This is what I'm talking about: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?712165-How-do-you-change-quot-WindowsApplication1-quot-when-I-right-click-on-my-program-taskbar

Comment: Did you try changing the assembly name?

Comment: I can't find a way to add an assembly name from the command line or where to add it in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way change the Assembly Name and/or Title if you all using Visual Studio

The file path is C:\dev\IRISNG\IRISNG\My Project\AssemblyInfo.vb

Here is a sample AssemblyInfo File

```
Imports System
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

' General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
' set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
' associated with an assembly.

' Review the values of the assembly attributes

<Assembly: AssemblyTitle("IRISNG")>
<Assembly: AssemblyDescription("")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyCompany("")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyProduct("IRISNG")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2007")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")> 

<Assembly: ComVisible(False)>

'The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
<Assembly: Guid("21df7a15-927f-494a-9f05-dd680390bedf")> 

' Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
'
'

          Major Version
'      Minor Version 
'      Build Number
'      Revision
'
' You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
' by using the '*' as shown below:
' <Assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")> 

<Assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")>
```

NOTE: Remember to click the Show files button at the top of the Solution Explorer

EDIT:
When using vbc.exe you need to set your AssemblyInfo.vb in the commandline e.g.

> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Vbc.exe /noconfig /imports:Microsoft.VisualBasic,System,System.Collections" /target:exe Module1.vb "My Project\AssemblyInfo.vb"

Notice the part "My Project\AssemblyInfo.vb"

If you still can't get it to work you can dump the output of msbuild to a log file. Then search it for the exact vbc command the IDE is excuting.

Example:
msbuild /v:diag myproject.vbproj >> log.txt

More Information at:
[Command Line Compiling Settings.settings using VBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418878/command-line-compiling-settings-settings-using-vbc)

Comment: I had already added that to my source code before. The title had no effect.

Comment: Check out the new Edit how to set the AssemblyInfo file in the vbc.exe commandline

Comment: Try a command like this:  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Vbc.exe /noconfig /imports:Microsoft.VisualBasic,System,System.Collections" /target:exe Module1.vb "My Project\AssemblyInfo.vb"